Backref not correctly counting duplicate citations
I am trying to use the backref package to count the number of citations and I am running into a problem where if a reference is cited multiple times on the same page, the total citation count is wrong. I am trying to follow the examples in this link and from this manual.

MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
    \ifcase #1 %
        No citations.%
    \or
        One citation on page #2.%
    \else
        #1 citations on page #2.%
\fi}
\renewcommand*{\backrefentrycount}[2]{%
    #1%
        \ifnum#2>1 %
    ~(#2)% 
\fi
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

This is the first occurrence \cite{A01}. Here we have a second occurrence, in the same section \cite{A01}. 

\section{Second section}

This is the third occurrence \cite{A01}.

\clearpage

\section{Second section}

This is the fourth occurrence \cite{A01}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}

Output:

Expected output:
Author, A. (2001). Alpha. 4 citations on page 1 (3) and 2 (1).
(i.e. the number between parentheses should ideally be the number of times it's cited on that page. However, my main concern is getting "Author, A. (2001). Alpha. 4 citations" correct.)

Hi @Marijn; I'm not sure I fully understand, but I'm quite certain the 2 refers to the fact that the citation occurs on 2 pages (as adding a third page with the citation does increase this to 3). Furthermore, it seems that the number between parenthesis, but divided by three, is actually the number of citations on that page, which seems quite arbitrary.

Well the problem is apacite, without it it works. Backref with hyperref counts the number of citations by writing something  into the aux everytime \Hy@backout is called. \Hy@backout is used inside the link start command and as apacite creates more links it counts every citation three times.
So one option would be to divide the number by three \inteval{#2/3}. But this assumes that every citation always creates two links.
A probably safer option is to remove \Hy@backout from \hyper@natlinkstart
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\makeatletter 
\def\hyper@natlinkstart#1{%
  %\Hy@backout{#1}%
  \hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.#1}%
  \def\hyper@nat@current{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
    \ifcase #1 %
        No citations.%
    \or
        One citation on page #2.%
    \else
        #1 citations on page #2.%
\fi}
\renewcommand*{\backrefentrycount}[2]{%
    #1%
        \ifnum#2>1 %
    ~(#2)% 
\fi
}

\begin{filecontents}{test-backref.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\section{First section}

This is the first occurrence \cite{A01}. Here we have a second occurrence, in the same section \cite{A01}. 

\section{Second section}

This is the third occurrence \cite{A01}.

\clearpage

\section{Second section}

This is the fourth occurrence \cite{A01}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test-backref.bib}

\end{document}



Great, thanks so much! The only minor thing is that the total number "2 citations [...]" still appears incorrect (although now I can at least manually get the total number), so if anyone know how to fix that :)

well #1 is without dupes (and it counts for all pages). Try with #3 citations on pages #4. or #3 citations on pages #2..

Perfect! You're an absolute legend, thanks!
